# libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2: cannot open shared object file

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, php, 18.04

After upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, I can't run `php` commands.

`php -v` shows me this:

```
php: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

```
$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114
```

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep -i libMagickWand-6.Q16.s
libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.3
libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.3
libMagickWand-6.Q16.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so
libMagickWand-6.Q16.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so
```

Running `ldconfig /usr/local/lib` did not help.

How can I fix this?

Comment: *libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2* is [from xenial](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libMagickWand-6). What is the output of `apt-cache policy libmagickwand-6.q16-3`? Did you tried to upgrade `php-imagick` package?

Comment: **pt-cache policy libmagickwand-6.q16-3**
`libmagickwand-6.q16-3:
  Instalado: 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6
  Candidato: 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6
  Tabela de versão:
 *** 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: php-imagick is already the newest version (3.4.3~rc2-2ubuntu4).

Answer (score 0):

> Little disclose before my answer: I happen to know and work with [Anthony Tailer](https://askubuntu.com/users/825036/anthony-tailer) and thus I have a little more insight of what as the root cause.

It turns out that this particular built of php wasn't updated when you update the OS and thus was linking to several old libraries that were replaced during the update.

It wasn't updated because it wasn't a package from an repository or anything like that. It was an binary built on his local machine.

In this situation the best approach is to rebuilt php so it can link to the new libraries.

Comment: I built IMagick after my php build then built the php extension using phpize and that worked without rebuilding php

Answer (score 0):

you could install by pecl

```
pecl install imagick
```

Greetings!